# Execution of commands in vimrc/vimscript

Tags: vimrc

If I add a command into my `vimrc`, such as:

```
:echom "Hello"
```

When I then open `vim`, I get the following:

```
LA-DEV-IM-MM:Avails david$ vim new
Hello!
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

To better my understanding of how/when the `vimrc` is executed:

- Why does `Hello!` print before "opening" vim?
- Why does it say "Press ENTER or..." instead of just loading vim?

My thinking was that the echo command would do the following:

- Open vim
- Do nothing, but if I type in `:messages` the echom would show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the help:

> :echom[sg] {expr1} ..
>   Echo the expression(s) as a true message, saving
>   the message in the **message-history**.

The `echom` command is supposed to print the message when invoked, as well as saving it to be shown by `messages`.

You can test this behaviour by using it directly in your command line, e.g `:echom "this is a test"`

If you put this in your vimrc, it will be executed when Vim starts. That's why you see the message.

Finally, you get the `press ENTER...` prompt because that's what happens when the command-line gets overpopulated by a command output. 
See `:h cmdheight`, which you can set to a higher value (default is 1, my recommendation would be 2) to avoid this.